# Existe anti-ddos no apache ? Quais medidas devo tomar pelo apache para prevenção?

Tags: apache, segurança, servidor, wampserver, ddos

Detalhando melhor:

Eu acredito que esteja sofrendo algum tipo de ataque, desconfiei e coloquei um anti ddos, e ele já bloqueou alguns endereços, isso me liberou a rede e voltou a normalizar o servidor, só que agora parece que surgiu algum ataque diferente, simplesmente colou em 100% de processamento a CPU e não sei o que fazer, peco que alguém me ajude com isso se possível me dando um norte, algum modulo que possa sugerir para o apache, eu sei que tem, mas nao sei qual usar.

Acrescentado 27/12/2017: Respondendo a minha própria pergunta, já que esta sendo difícil e ddos e chato toda hora o firewall bloqueia e isso consome memoria do sistema e etc, eu encontrei um modulo anti-ddos para apache, mod security, vou tentar levantar informações sobre ele para construir algum conhecimento sobre o assunto através desta questão, encontrei algumas medidas para se proteger pelo próprio apache, começando por medidas simples, ate chegar no ddos, na minha opinião se for solucionado pelo próprio apache acredito que consuma menos memoria e CPU do que usar programas externos, não se trata de proteção apenas para ddos, mas se alguém quer proteção por que não tomar mais de uma medidas, o foco da questao e o ddos, mas estarei aplicando algumas das medidas que estou postando no link do artigo que encontrei, https://www.petefreitag.com/item/505.cfm

Comment: O Apache não limita o processo por usuários que acessam o site, nem tem como identificar um usuário, o que você limita são requisições baseado em uma origem de um possível ataque (por exemplo), fora que limitar no Apache não vai impedir altos consumos do banco de dados por exemplo. Fora que não da para afirmar que é um ataque ou uma falha geral não detectada por vocês, o processador chegar a 100% pode ser simplesmente uma série de scripts que foram escritos não pensando na otimização...

Comment: ... eu mesmo tive este problema, parecia um ataque ao BD, mas na verdade eram várias varias conexões desnecessárias por segundo que ocorriam, e isto tudo era ocasionado por uma série de scripts que faziam conexão sem necessidade, até mesmo aonde eu estava fazendo uso de MEMCACHE o banco conectava, o que consumia tanto o limite do banco quanto 'o processador'.

Comment: O anti-ddos que vc instalou provavelmente já resolve o problema principal, módulos para apache não vão ser tão eficientes, se puder resolver antes de checar "ao servidor HTTP" será melhor, fora que como já disse esse "segundo ataque" pode nem ser um ataque.

Comment: Puts, realmente não era outro ataque, oque tava acontecendo apesar do site ter scripts meio antigos era o antivírus do windows server 2016 que estava conflitando com o anti-ddos, o ataque tava surtindo efeito pela falta de recurso no sistema gerada pelo conflito dos dois. Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda, agora vou dar uma estudada para ver o que pode ser feito em relação a otimização que eu sei que esta precisando ser revisada.